# ERROR: syntax error at or near "my_var" in my_var := select

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an sql file where I have this:

```
aa := select id from category where id = 1;
```

and an error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "aa"
```

I've also tried this in "psql" session.

Why the error?

Comment: `select id into aa from category where id = 1;`

Comment: Also I don't see any mistakes in your query. Do you have anything before `aa`

Comment: Show us your complete function. In PL/pgSQL variables need to be read using `select id into aa from category ...`. See the manual for details: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW

Comment: @Prdp, that creates a new table. I don't need it. I just want to save the result into a variable.

Comment: @Dimon - That will happen in `SQL Server`

Comment: @Prdp, that creates a new table. I don't need it. I just want to save the result into a variable. and that's a single request, not a part of a function.

Comment: You can't have variables outside of PL/pgSQL functions (or anonymous blocks). What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you think you need a variable? And which SQL client are you using? Some offer client side variables "outside" of SQL

Answer (score 1):

In psql you can use psql variables:

```
select id as aa from category where id = 1 \gset
\echo :aa
```

(see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-VARIABLES)

In PL/pgSQL use `into`:

```
DO $$
declare
  aa integer;
begin
  select id into aa from category where id = 1;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to save this 'insert' into your variable, try like this:

```
declare
variable_a varchar2(2000) := 'select id from category where id = 1;';
begin
 execute immediate variable_a;
end;
```

Comment: That is invalid for Postgres